# Does abstract state for router Angular 2+ exists?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I need implementation abstract state route in Angular 2+.
For this moment found two solutions instead 'abstract' state.
The first is 'resolver'. It helps you can resolve data troubles, and get it in child components by `ActivatedRoute['data']`.
https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve
The second is use `pathMath: 'prefix'` option  for resolve layout tasks.
https://angular.io/guide/router#redirecting-routes

```
 {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'first-children',
        component: FirstChildrenComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'second-children',
        component: SecondChildrenComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
```

Are other solutions exist, can anybody help?